# App crashes,dynamic edittexts,lists,etc

Tags: java, android, crash

I've been making changes for the past 2-3 hours,trying to figure out where i went wrong.I think i made it worse by trying to repair it...Could you please take a look and tell me where i went wrong ? 
What i'm trying to do is this : create editexts dynamically(2 every time button is pressed).The values go 2 lists(one for each column of editexts).From there they multiply with eachother and go in the 3rd list which should then add all the values and give me the grand total.

I know it's not complete but i stopped going further because it started crashing...
Here's the code :

```
    List<EditText> allpret = new ArrayList<EditText>();
List<EditText> allcant = new ArrayList<EditText>();
List<Float> alltotal = new ArrayList<Float>();


public void produsnou(View v) {
    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setHint("Produs");
    l1.addView(et);

    LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
    et2.setHint("Cantitate");
    et2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

    allcant.add(et2);
    l2.addView(et2);

    LinearLayout l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
    et3.setHint("Pret");
    et3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    l3.addView(et3);

    allpret.add(et3);

}

float temp=0;

public void calculeaza(View v) {
    String[] cant = new String[allcant.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < allcant.size(); j++) {
        cant[j] = allcant.get(j).getText().toString();}

        String[] pret = new String[allcant.size()];


        for (int k = 0; k < allpret.size(); k++) {
            pret[k] = allpret.get(k).getText().toString();}

         Float[] totaluri = new Float[alltotal.size()];

         for(int l=0;l<allpret.size();l++){


            Float temp = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);
            alltotal.add(temp);

            totaluri[l] = temp  ;   }



        TextView totalf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        totalf.setText("Total: " +totaluri[1]); }
```

And here is the logcat :

```
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3704)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17318)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3699)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    ... 11 more
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    at com.example.testlayout.MainActivity.calculeaza(MainActivity.java:76)
06-09 04:03:58.230: E/AndroidRuntime(22651):    ... 14 more
06-09 04:03:58.260: D/dalvikvm(22651): GC_CONCURRENT freed 234K, 11% free 7248K/8135K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 36ms
```

Comment: Also,how can i make my logcat look nice,so you guys won't have to edit my ugly logcat every time,heh.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Float is an object that contains a primitive float.  Its not a number.  Its an object that holds a number.

This line seems super squirrely:

```
Float temp = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);
```

What are you trying to do with this?

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
float floatValue = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);
Float temp = Float(floatValue);
```

You can, of course, concatenate those into one line.  But I think its easier to show you what should be happening this way.

Answer (score 0):

So you defined the `alltotal` ArrayList at the beginning, *but* it has no elements when you do `new Float[alltotal.size()]`, so you end up with a `totaluri` array that is empty. Which fails when you try to save `temp` into the L'th position (0):

```
 for (int k = 0; k < allpret.size(); k++) {
     pret[k] = allpret.get(k).getText().toString();}
     Float[] totaluri = new Float[alltotal.size()]; //<----- totaluri = []
     for(int l=0;l<allpret.size();l++){
        Float temp = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);
        alltotal.add(temp);
        totaluri[l] = temp  ; //<---- totaluri[0] is not a valid index
```